# Gas no longer flowing to Weber grill

Tags: natural-gas

I have a Weber Spirit E-310 Natural Gas Grill.   I installed the pipe and connector myself for the natural gas.  In the beginning, it was very difficult to connect the grill hose to the quick connect connector.  (I never understood why it was always so difficult) Over time, it got easier.

The grill has worked fine for almost 2 years.  Then one day, gas didn't flow when I inserted the quick connect.  My only guess is that the bridge on the hose is bent just enough to not trigger gas to flow.

I have two questions:

1. Is there something wrong with my original installation? (Why was the hose always so difficult to insert?)
2. Is buying a new hose the wrong solution? (the old one didn't even last 2 years)

[image]
[image]

Comment: `it was very difficult to connect the grill hose` ... isn't natural gas connector fitting different from a propane connector fitting?

Comment: It might be as simple as the regulator failing. Either call Weber and they'll talk you through testing, or there are bound to be troubleshooting guides online.

Comment: I used Weber's email support.  They're sending a new quick connect and hose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weber sent a new hose and quick connect.  This was much easier to connect than the original and now the grill works again.

Comment: Sadly, had you called them 2 years ago, you probably wouldn't have had to struggle with it for more than a couple of days waiting for the new one to arrive. Call it a lesson learned - if it's brand new and it ain't working right, ask! :)